# LXDM login doesn't work

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xfce, authentication, lxde

I installed Arch Linux on VirtualBox. As a login manager, I've chosen LXDM and XFCE for the window manager. I've set `/usr/bin/startxfce4` as the `session` in `etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf`.

The problem is that when the lxdm login window appears, and when I try typing my password in and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> nothing happens. I see the same screen that I was seeing before I clicked on my username.

Answer (score 2):

Solution (weird but worked for me) : open `/usr/share/xsessions/xfce.desktop` and replace

```
Name=Xfce Session
```

By

```
Name=Xfce_Session
```

Comment: I do not have such file.

Answer (score 0):

In the login screen select a desktop different than "DEFAULT". It worked for me.